# How to check if selected file is a directory or regular file?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following file input:

```js
const file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);
});
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

You can Drag and Drop folder into this input. But how do I know if a user has dropped directory or a regular file?

Comment: check the `type` field for directories it is empty

Comment: The `type` field wont work because if you upload a `README` file with no extension it's still empty. The size probably won't work because it's also 0 on empty files and not just folders. I would expect a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to fail on directories, though I've not tried, You can just ask users to not upload empty files and check the `size > 0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[EDIT]
Added error name check.
Thanks for the suggestions, @Cid and @DanielCuadra.

When a directory is selected, the FileReader can't read its content, so an error is produced. Here is an example of how you could implement a *File Validator* for the uploads.

This example has full suport on all modern browsers.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.onchange = (e) => {
    const file = input.files[0]
    isThisAFile(file)
        .then(validFile => console.log('Woohoo! Got a File:', validFile))
        .catch(error => console.log('Bummer, looks like a dir:', file, error))

}
function isThisAFile(maybeFile) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (maybeFile.type !== '') {
            return resolve(maybeFile)
        }
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            if (
                reader.error &&
                (
                    reader.error.name === 'NotFoundError' ||
                    reader.error.name === 'NotReadableError'
                )) {
                return reject(reader.error.name)
            }
            resolve(maybeFile)
        }
        reader.readAsBinaryString(maybeFile)
    })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is accepted answer because this method is supported by all modern browsers and will work for every `Blob` object, no matter where it comes from. Thanks @apokryfos for pointing this method first in the comments

Comment: This won't work for large files. They will provide an error and will be considered as a folder

Comment: This can be fixed using `if (reader.error && reader.error.name === 'NotFoundError')`

Comment: This won't work for Firefox. This is fixed using `if (reader.error && (reader.error.name === 'NotFoundError' || reader.error.name === 'NotReadableError'))`

Answer (score 2):

You should provide additional attributes to your input tag

```
<input id="file" type="file" webkitdirectory directory multiple />
```

then **change** event would provide you info about all files inside your folder with file path inside file object (but not about folder itself).

Comment: However this will not work in IE11, and only Safari >= 11, see https://caniuse.com/#search=directory

Answer (score 1):

the directory can be detected with "webkitGetAsEntry" method but it is not supported widely [here is the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem/webkitGetAsEntry)

```js
const file = document.getElementById('file');
file.addEventListener('change', e => {
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);
});

file.addEventListener('drop',onDrop);

function onDrop(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  var items = e.dataTransfer.items;
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
 var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0, item; item = items[i]; ++i) {

    var entry = item.webkitGetAsEntry();
    var obj = {
   name: entry.name,
   isDirectory: entry.isDirectory,
   isFile: entry.isFile
  }
    result.push(obj);
  }
  
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file" />
```

Comment: Also you can do `fileInput.webkitEntries` to see similar result